# Is having multiple xmls for one activity a bad practice?

Tags: android, android-xml

Let's say I have two different xml files and I choose which one to use through setContentView() in my activity's java file. Is that ok? Why should I create a different activity with almost the same code?

Comment: It depends upon your app/business logic....

Comment: @niks I did. My question isn't based on any particular case. Just wanted to know if having multiple xmls per activity is bad or not in general bacause I read all over the internet that it is and no one said why. Sorry if that wasn't clear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user would expect to see the first one, on pressing Back from the second, then you should have two activities(or restart the same activity with the new content), to take advantage of the Android navigation system; otherwise, you can have more than one in the same activity.

Comment: I see, didn't think of that... So it's nothing like the goto taboo huh? Cause that's the impression I got when searching around...